# Optimising tensor operations under memory constraints

Tags: performance-tuning, memory, tensors, memoization

Let `riem` is a free variable with `riem ∈ Arrays[{4, 4, 4, 4}` as assumption. Let:

`val = TensorConstract[TensorProduct[riem, riem, riem], {{4,5}}]`

Let `riemVals` be an actual `{4, 4, 4, 4}` tensor whose indices have symbolic values.

---

I'm interested in computing  `val /. (riem-> riemVals)`.  I'm "guessing" there are two ways Mathematica could do this internally:

1) Compute `v1 =TensorProduct[riemVals, riemVals, riemVals]` then compute the result as  `TensorConstract[v1,{{4,5}}]`.

2) Note that `val` is equivalent to:

`TensorProduct[TensorConstract[TensorProduct[riem, riem], {{4,5}}],riem]`.

Compute  `v1= TensorProduct[riemVals, riemVals]`. Then `v2= TensorConstract[v1,{{4,5}}]`. Then the result as  `TensorProduct[v1, riemVals]`.

---

Now, what's the difference between these two? Obviously they give us the same result, but in the first approach we have to store a $4^{12}$ tensor in memory as intermediate value, while in the second one we only have to store a  $4^{10}$ tensor. The idea being that, when your maximum memory is constrained, it pays off to move `TensorConstract` inwards to the expression so you can do it as early as possible before you do the `TensorProduct`.

My question is: does Mathematica take the memory-efficient approach when doing these types of operations? If not, is there any way to implement the evaluation/computation in a controlled manner such that the result will be calculated in a memory-efficient way (compute and prioritize forms where the `TensorCotract` is made early)?

Comment: "does Mathematica take the memory-efficient approach when doing these types of operations?" Well, you can simply try it, right? But I think the anwser is "no". _Mathematica_ just does what you tell it to do. Moreover, I think `TensorProduct[riem.riem, riem]` should be slightly more efficient in this case. This performs the contraction already without forming the tensor product.

Comment: I can "hand-tune" individual formulas when I need to, but what would be best is a way to teach Mathematica to do these kinds of things in a memory-efficient manner without me holding its hand each time. I'm guessing something like a custom replacement function that takes an abstract tensor formula and a list of replacement rules and outputs the result (but does it in a memory efficient way). Either that or just get more ram. :))